# Segmentation fault when reading with read

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault, system

I'm working on an assignment where part of it is to read from stdin using the system function `read()`, and then print the last 10 lines and so far I've got this:

```
int tailSTD()
{
    char *lines = malloc(1);
    char buffer[10];
    int cmdCount = 0, buffCount, rState;
    while((rState = read(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, 10)) > 0)
    {
        if(rState < 0)
        {
            if(errno == EINTR) rState = 0;
            else
            {
                perror("read()");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if (rState == 0) break;

        lines = realloc(lines, strlen(lines) + strlen(buffer));
        for(buffCount = 0; buffCount < strlen(buffer); buffCount++)
        {
            lines[cmdCount] = buffer[buffCount];
            cmdCount++; 
        }
    }
    printf("do we get this far?");
    printSTDLines(lines);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I get a segmentation fault somewhere along the loop and I\m not sure where, this worked with `fgets()`, and I simply modified it just because it just HAS to be done with `read()`. It's probably very messy, for which I apologize, but it just has to be done in this manner. I know the problem is here, because it never gets to the last `printf` before `printSTDLines`. 
Here's `printSTDLines` if you need it:

```
void printSTDLines(char *lines)
{
    int lineCount = strlen(lines), newLineCount = 0;
    while(newLineCount < 10)
    {
        if(lines[lineCount] == '\n')
        {
            newLineCount++;
        }
        lineCount--;
    }
    int readSize = strlen(lines) - lineCount;
    for(lineCount = readSize; lineCount < sizeof(lines); lineCount++)
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &lines[lineCount], 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `printSTDLine()`?

Comment: that's just it, that function (now fixed) doesn't work for `stdin`, that's why i started the `stdin` version from scratch, if you have an idea how to get that other version going for stdin, I'm happy to hear it

Comment: Your problem is assuming that the `buffer` contains a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `strlen(lines)` but you never `nul` terminate it. The `strlen()` function expects to find a `'\0'` byte to tell where the end of the "*string*" is, you don't add that byte to any of your arrays and that invokes *undefined behavior*, one possible consequence of that is a segmentation fault.

Also, this

```
for(lineCount = readSize; lineCount < sizeof(lines); lineCount++)
```

seems wrong, the `sizeof` operator doesn't work for an dynamically allocated array, in this case `lines` is a pointer and that means `sizeof` is giving you the size of a pointer and by no means the length of the array which is apparently what you want.

To use the length of the array inside `printSTDLine()` you need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I always confuse `sizeof` and `strlen` on the first go of coding, and it always takes me ages to figure out that that's the problem, but where in the loop should i `nul` terminate the string?

Comment: It doesn't matter where. When you pass it to `strlen()` it MUST have a `'\0'` somewhere. In practice it should be after the last character.